# JMS consumer on a different JVM

Tags: jms, message-driven-bean, jboss-mdb

My application puts in messages in a JMS queue. A bean that implements MDB and MessageListener pops messages from this queue. All this happens on a single JVM .

What I want to do is: I want the MDB and the other instances that it would get from pool for concurrent processing to run on a different JVM. How can I do it? The application server that I am using is JBOSS 4.0.5.GA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to split your application into "producer" part (stays in the same server) and "consumer" part (MDBs moved to another server), and still be able to communicate.

In this case you need to configure the `ConnectionFactory` in the "consumer" server to plug in to the "producer" server's MQ. [Have you read this part of JBoss 4.x docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Messaging_on_JBoss-Specifying_the_MDB_JMS_Provider.html)?